# php - class extending alternative

Tags: php

I have a main class that I add around a dozen child classes to similar to Example #2.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this. I know I could do "extends" on classes (Example #1) however in order to be able to have one variable with access to all extended class functions, I'd have to "daisy chain" the extensions and then create a new class reference on the very last extension - this option is not what I'm looking for.

```
Example #1:

class main {
    function _construct(){}
    function main_function1(){}
    function main_function2(){}
}
class child1 extends main{
    function _construct(){}
    function child_function1(){}
    function child_function2(){}
}
class child2 extends child1 {
    function _construct(){}
    function child_function3(){}
    function child_function4(){}
}
$main = new child2();
$main->child_function1();
$main->child_function2();
$main->child_function3();
$main->child_function4();
```

Here is what I'm currently doing.

```
Example #2:

<?php

class main {
    function _construct(){}
    function main_function1(){}
    function main_function2(){}
}
class child1 {
    function _construct($main){$this->main = $main;}
    function child_function1(){}
    function child_function2(){}
}
class child2 {
    function _construct($main){$this->main = $main;}
    function child_function3(){}
    function child_function4(){}
}
$main = new main();
$main->child1 = new child1($main);
$main->child2 = new child2($main);

$main->child1->child_function1();
$main->child1->child_function2();
$main->child2->child_function3();
$main->child2->child_function4();

?>
```

Is Example #2 the best way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't quite get what you are aiming for. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for here. It seems like you are looking for building a model where one object references to another from it self, and not extending classes with subclasses?

Comment: Method 2 is most likely  what you want to do, using [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). One of the best litmus tests of whether you should use inheritance is if the sentence "ChildClass is a ParentClass" makes sense (of course substituting your own class names).

Comment: Your problem will probably be most easily solved with [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

Comment: composition is not inheritance. So I think it really depends..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing

```
class child {
    function __construct($main){$this->main = $main;}
}
```

in **Example 2** you would pass the `$main` instance as a property for `child` in the constructor. In my opinion this would make sense, if `$main` is a container that provides information for `child` - which is useful if you would like to avoid having a constructor with many many arguments. According to your naming, it doesn't look like `main` is a container. Be aware, that you are creating a dependency between `child` and `main` then because if you want to instantiate `child`, you always need an instance of `main` in advance! What you are also doing in **Example 2** is creating [circular references](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/whats-wrong-with-circular-references):

```
$main = new main();
$main->child1 = new child1($main);
$main->child2 = new child2($main);
```

You would be able to call `$main->child1->main` then which means a high coupling between `main` and `child`. So I'd rather not say "go for Example 2".

In your case it rather sounds like `child` actually **is** a special case of `main`, like the relationship between fruit (main) and apple (child). That makes using `extends` much more reasonable. You seem to be unsure, because you have many child classes extending `main`. To me this sound just normal, if all the `child` classes have a similar purpose and share some basic functionalty which is provided by `main`. But I'm not quite sure what your goal actually is.

Comment: Is it considered bad practice/design if you do this?

Answer (score 0):

Extending classes can break encapsulation, so depending on your classes it might be best to keep your objects separated as in example #2. You could have a loading function to make setting up the main class easier:

```
class main {
    function load($class){
        $this->$class = new $class();
    }
}
$main = new main();
$main->load('child1');
$main->child1->child_function1();
```

Comment: While it is true that you can do this it breaks IoC and SoC

Comment: [This](https://prague2013.drupal.org/session/dont-be-stupid-grasp-solid) should give you a good overview of the concepts

Answer (score -1):

In php, You have two options. Either (in 2020) inject your Helper Class in another class as suggested in the first answer or in PHP you can use [traits](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

Traits are similar to classes but their constructors cannot be public.
It's difficult to use Dependency injection on traits but traits can extend existing classes with methods and they can access the parent methods of their respective classes.

With traits anyway you cannot override the parent methods, you can only add the methods to the stack.

Another downside of traits is that, when you use the parent methods of the containing class, type hinting is not well supported in some IDEs. So in order to get type hinting working you'll need some workarounds.